# Keras: how to reset optimizer state?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to reset optimizer state in keras?

Looking at Optimizer class I can't see such a method:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/613aeff37a721450d94906df1a3f3cc51e2299d4/keras/optimizers.py#L60

Also what is actually `self.updates` and `self.weights`?

Comment: This is not a simple task indeed! ML should be hard, isn't it, dear TF team? One popular use case for optimizers which is related to this question is saving/loading them from a checkpoint. Workaround for this usecase is to not save them. There is a special flag for this: `model.save(... , include_optimizer=False)`!

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an "easy" way to reset the "states", but you can always simply recompile your model with a new optimizer (model's weights are preserved):

```
newOptimizer = Adadelta()
model.compile(optimizer=newOptimizer)
```

You can also use the method `set_weights(weightsListInNumpy)` (not recommended), in the base class `Optimizer`, but this would be rather cumbersome as you would need to know all initial values and shapes, which sometimes may not be trivial zeroes .

Now, the property `self.weights` doesn't do much, but the functions that save and load optimizers will save and load this property. It's a list of tensors and should not be changed directly. At most use `K.set_value(...)` in each entry of the list. You can see the `weights` in saving the optimizer in the [`_serialize_model` method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/saving.py#L44).

The `self.updates` are something a little more complex to understand. It stores the variables that will be updated with every batch that is processed by the model in training. But it's a **symbolic** graph variable.

The `self.updates`, as you can see in the code, is always appended with a `K.update(var, value)` or `K.update_add(var, value)`. This is the correct way to tell the graph that these values should be updated every iteration.

Usually, the updated vars are `iterations`, `params` (the model's weights), `moments`, `accumulators`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a universal method for this, but you should be able to reset the state of your optimizer by initializing the variables holding it. This would need to be done with the TensorFlow API, though. The state variables depend on the specific kind of optimizer. For example, if you have a [`Adam`](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) optimizer ([source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/optimizers.py#L436-L524)), you could do the following:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K

optimizer = Adam(...)
# These depend on the optimizer class
optimizer_state = [optimizer.iterations, optimizer.lr, optimizer.beta_1,
                   optimizer.beta_2, optimizer.decay]
optimizer_reset = tf.variables_initializer(optimizer_state)

# Later when you want to reset the optimizer
K.get_session().run(optimizer_reset)
```

Answer (score -1):

The optimizer is just adjusting the wheihts of your model, thus the information is stored in the model, not in the optimizer.

That means you can't reset an optimizer in a way you might think. You need to reset (or maybe easyier, recreate) your model.

That means you also can optimize your model with an optimizer A, stop after some epochs, and continue optimizing your model with optimizer B not loosing the progress optimizer A made allready.

I don't know exactly what `self.updates` and `self.weights` are there for. But because those are internal variables of the class someone needs to know/read about the optimizer class itself and understand its code. Here we need to wait fore someone who dived deeper into the sourcecode of keras.

**EDIT**

You can just recreate your optimizer for example:

```
model = Seqeuential()
...
...
...

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr = 5, loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr = 0.5, loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

With the above code you train 10 epochs with learning rate 5, compile your model with a new optimizer, and continue for another 10 epochs with learning rate 0.5. The weights which you could also call your training progress do not get lost if you compile your model again.

Comment: I don't want to reset model weights I just want to reset optimizer state, i.e. optimizer parameters (lr, etc.)

Comment: Many optimizers contain information of their own, such as moving averages of gradients or learning rates for individual parameters. Resetting the optimizer would throw away this information, and would probably lead to worse performance (at least over the short term, until the optimizer re-learns the moving averages, individual learning rates, etc.).